# Mysql statement with unique id created

Tags: mysql, unique

I would like to ask how the mysql statement should be written in which unique ids are created in individual result rows (but actually not existed in the table)

For example, the content of table 'ABC' is:

> name type
>
> John A
>
> Mary B
>
> Peter C
>
> Fred A
>
> Gary C
>
> Susan D
>
> Alan A

When mysql statement SELECT * from ABC where type = 'A' is used, the result is

> name type
>
> John A
>
> Fred A
>
> Alan A

But I would like to put unique ids in each row of the mysql result, but the ids are NOT actually put in the table. For example,

> (newid) name type
>
> 1 John A
>
> 2 Fred A
>
> 3 Alan A

Then the row can be further searched by using the following mysql statement.

> SELECT * from ABC WHERE (newid) = '1'

The result is:

> (newid) name type
>
> 1 John A

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an autoincrement column

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Does ALTER TABLE really insert a table in mysql?

Comment: Alter table   add a column  not a table  .. and the autoincrement add the uniqe id

Comment: Then do we use SELECT * from 'your_table' WHERE id = 'X' to extract certain row information after that?

Comment: Yes ... once you have altered the table you have new (real) column and you can simply usinng a where condition eg: SELECT * from ABC WHERE id =  1   (is a numeric type so you don't need quote around the value)

Comment: Do I need to rename the table from one to another in ALERT TABLE statement to avoid confusion with the original table "ABC"? Thanks.

Comment: If you need to preserver the original table you should copy the table and work on the copy ..  but try evaluate the fact you can use ever the unique id

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a <kbd>**`PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`**</kbd> field in your table.

Do the following and check:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`
ADD COLUMN `id_primary`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_primary`);
```

So **in your case** it would be like:

```
ALTER TABLE `ABC`
ADD COLUMN `id_primary`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_primary`);
```

**Note:**

Here `id_primary` field is considered to be your `newid`

This is how your table looks like before this update. [**See Demo before altering table**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a626ba/1/0)

After the update look at your table now [**See Demo after altering table**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7107c5/1/0)

Comment: Then do we use SELECT * from 'your_table' WHERE id_primary = 'X' to extract certain row information after that?

Comment: Do I need to rename the table from one to another in ALERT TABLE statement to avoid confusion with the original table "ABC"? Thanks.

Comment: No.just use `ABC` in place of `your_table.` I've updated the answer. please check now.

Comment: Can we add "WHERE X = Y" after ALTER TABLE statement?

Comment: yes you can. You can run query like `SELECT * from ABC WHERE id_primary = 1`.

Comment: I've added demo in my answer. please check those. @CKH

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable to achieve that, but like @1000111 said, the right thing you should do is alter your table:

```
select *
from (
    select abc.*, @newid := @newid + 1 as newid
    from abc
    cross join (select @newid := 0) t
    where type = 'A'
) t1
where t1.newid = 1
```

Comment: @Strawberry I know that, but as I said, the right thing is alter his table. I think there is no need to be so mean to say "meaningless", SO is an open, kind, great community, what you are saying can let us or just me dare to answer a question, is it your aim or SO's aim?

Comment: @Strawberry You want some kind of meaning, all right, need I delete this answer? Or your comment is priceless for OP? I don't mind anyone gives a comment but not by rude way or your honest!!! Thanks for your honest.

Comment: In the absence of a PRIMARY KEY, it would be best to delete this answer.

Comment: @Strawberry No matter what I doubt why did you delete your comment? If this answer makes OP be more confused or feel my impolite manner, I'll delete it. But from you, I've learned how a man can be so mean.

Comment: The same words to you. I really don't follow your point. @Strawberry

Comment: OK. I'll try again: Rows in an RDBMS database represent unordered sets; they have no order. Instead, any order is established in the query itself, by means of an ORDER BY clause. Without such a clause, the order in which rows are returned is arbitrary or indeterminate, or without meaning, hence 'meaningless'. However, there's another problem here. The PRIMARY KEY is undefined, so we cannot be certain of the OP's intent. By definition ALL tables in a relational database should have a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Strawberry Please think, please, please, don't I really know the so-called fact you said? I just don't follow what the way you have said or the way you comment. No matter what, I also want to give OP an answer, and I intend to do that. All right?